# Remove namespaces from Xpath expression

Tags: regex, xpath

I need a way to remove namespaces from an XPath expression, e.g if it's something like this:

```
/ns1:ElementOne/ElementTwo/ns2:ElementThree
```

it should become

```
/ElementOne/ElementTwo/ElementThree
```

Namespaces could differ within the XPath (ns1, ns2 in the example above) and can be applied at the beginning of the Xpath, e.g.

```
ns3:ElementFour
```

Regex? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why remove the namespaces?? Get to learn how to use XML namespaces and embrace them instead of fighting them!

Comment: A parser I am currently forced to use does its own thing with namespaces in XML document, but an input Xpath string has to have none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex bellow matches the namespace format:

```
[\w]+:
```

EDIT:

For the ancestor part you can use the updated regex:

```
[\w]+:(?!:)
```

So the final solution does the following, It searches for the previously stated structure with all alphanumerical + underscore string format followed by a ':' character which is not followed by a second ':' character. Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful! Just what the the doctor ordered, thanks! 

I am not very strong in regex, would you mind to explain how this matching works for both cases above?

Comment: well this regex matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore) using the "[\w]" part, it matches it multiple times by using the "+" and it also requires the ":" character at the end of the string structure.

Comment: Thanks again, this is short and brilliant. I hope you don't mind me posting this on my blog http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/03/20/remove-namespaces-from-xpath-expression/

Comment: Another one for ya :) Xpath can contain axis which consist of double coluns, e.g.  `ancestor::/ElementOne/ns1:ElementTwo`  
these :: parts should be left alone, e.g above expression needs to be converted into  `ancestor::/ElementOne/ElementTwo`  can the regex expression be modified to exclude these?  Thanks!

Comment: So i've came up with a new regex that should help you.

Comment: Thanks again, works like magic. I really gotta study RegEx in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Idon't know the format for xpath names, but the xml spec seems fuzzy to me about the application of the colons as namespace delimeter vs valid name character that must be accepted by processors. Although colons should be used only as namespace delimiter.

So, minus the unicode codepoint validation -

To match up to the last colon:

`[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*(?<=:)`

To match up to the first colon:

`(?:[A-Za-z_][\w.-]*|):`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. In this case namespace starts with a letter (which can be preceded either by / or by nothing) consists of letters and numbers and ends with : delimiter.

Is there a way to match to the first colon, but do that match multiple times for every occurance?